# How to pass an empty array to inherited constructor

Tags: solidity

I'm trying to write a contract that inherits from the ERC-777 contract on OpenZeppelin. This contract has a constructor with the following signature:

```
constructor(
    string memory name_,
    string memory symbol_,
    address[] memory defaultOperators_
)
```

In my inherited contract, I'm trying to write a constructor that takes no arguments and provide defaults for the inherited constructor. Here is what I tried:

```
contract MyCoin is ERC777 {
    constructor() ERC777("MyCoin", "MYC", []) {
    }
}
```

But I receive the following error:

> TypeError: Unable to deduce common type for array elements.
> --> contracts/MyCoin.sol:7:45:
> |
> 7 |     constructor() ERC777("MyCoin", "MYC", []) {
> |                                             ^^
>
> Error HH600: Compilation failed

Is it possible to provide an empty array to the inherited constructor?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I figured it out. The way to do this is:

```
constructor() ERC777("MyCoin", "MYC", new address[](0)) {
}
```